# How are Hydrogen Atoms Described in Standard Model?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, quantum-electrodynamics, hydrogen

Specifically, in order to calculate the quantities like emissivity or the cross section of photon resonant scattering by hydrogen atoms, what logical deduction route should we follow, starting from the Lagrangian of Standard Model (SM)?

**My Thoughts:**

I think the problem would be devided into two steps:

1. Assuming non-relativistic energy scale in SM, deduce the Lagrangian of quantum electrodynamics (QED) with electrons, protons and photons. We also would like to confirm that the internal structure of protons does not affect the dynamics of the system.
2. Starting from the QED Lagrangian deduced above, construct hydrogen atoms and describe the interaction with photons.

The step 1 seems to be the subject of the latest research, since I heard it was only recently that the calculation of hadron mass was succeeded. Since I'm not familliar with the quantum chromodynamics, I will think again after studying it.

As for the step 2, since the bounded states of electrons should be considered, the perturbation theory doesn't work. I can naively find two different ways, say 2A and 2B:

- 2A. The way to reduce it to the familiar problem in quantum mechanics (QM)

  - 2A-1. Fix the gauge and devide the gauge field into quasi-static Coulomb potential and dynamic radiation field.
  - 2A-2. As for protons and electrons, quit thinking with field operators, focusing on one-particle states, and change the problem into that of QM with the Coulomb potential.
  - 2A-3. Under the Born–Oppenheimer approximation, calculate Einstein coefficients, applying Fermi's golden rule to the states of the bounded electron and photons. Otherwise, calculate the cross section of scattering with the old-fashioned scattering theory (Lippmann–Schwinger equation).
- 2B. The straightfoward way as the quantum field theory

  - 2B-1. Show that "hydrogen atom field" expressing appropriate internal structure (electron orbital) can be constructed in the daily energy scale, and deduce the Lagrangian of it.
  - 2B-2. From the interaction Lagrangian of the hydrogen atom field and the gauge field, construct Feynman rules and calcuate vertex functions. Then, calculate the cross section with the LSZ reduction formula.

**Detailed Question:**

I'm familliar with the calculating method of 2A-3. I would like to fill the logical gap up to 2A-3, but not actually done yet. I'm grad if you tell me some refferences which would help me. And I also expect that there are some actual researches related to 2B, but have not found yet. Is there any related theories?

[The atomic database
by NIST](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/lines_form.html) refers to [Wiese & Fuhr (2009)](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3077727), in which the transition probabilities of hydrogen atom were calculated with the Dirac field before the second quantization (Dirac field as a wave function). It would be classified as the method of 2A-3. I've never seen actual results calculated with the method of 2B-2.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: If you start from the Standard Model and assume everything is non-relativistic, what you get is standard quantum mechanics. QFT is essentially just QM with the addition of particle creation and destruction, and particle creation destruction only happens at relativistic energy scales.